# Need to run threads groups in Jmeter when previous threads group's all threads is started

Tags: jmeter

I have two thread group Thread group 1 and Thread group 2 in my test plan. Thread Group 1 has 15 users and Thread Group 2 has 20 users. Now I want to run my thread group 2 after  threads ( 15 users) of Thread Group has been started.

Is there anyway to run like this.

Answer (score 0):

Add [Startup Delay](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) to group 2 which is greater than Ramp-Up Period of group 1

Make sure Test Plan Run Test Group consecutively check-box is **un checked**

Comment: If i checked Test Plan Run Test Group consecutively check-box, then thread group 2 will run after running the complete script of Thread group 1. But I want to run Thread group 2, only after starting of all users.

Comment: @ravikumar true, I removed that line

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this: use following steps:

1. Add multiple Thread Group in your Test Plan.
2. In this example, Thread Group - One has 10 Threads and Thread Group - Two has 1 Thread
3. To start Thread of Thread Group 2 after all the Threads of Thread Group 1, make sure you keep following settings in Thread Group 2

   ```
   Check Scheduler check box
   Start Up Delay should be greater than Ramp up period of previous Thread Group
   Make sure to enter duration as well, otherwise you will get the error.
   ```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don not want to use scheduler, as my aim to run script for specific loop count, not for specific time.

Comment: Yes you can do that. Keep Loop Count as per your wish and Duration high, so that when you finish your loop the test will stop.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) to first Thread Group and use the following [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function as the condition

   ```
   ${__groovy(ctx.getThreadGroup().numberOfActiveThreads() == ctx.getThreadGroup().numberOfThreads,)}
   ```
2. Now you have a "trigger" which fires when all the threads defined in Thread Group are started. Now you can use i.e. [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter/) in order to "tell" the 2nd Thread Group that it's good to go. Check out [SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx) for reference implementation.

Comment: Hey I have added If controller  to first thread and added function. As I am begginer kindly explain step 2 in detail.